# rails installing mysql2 -v '0.3.20' instead of mysql -v '0.3.16'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mysql2

i am using a Windows 8 machine and trying to run a ruby on rails application.

When I run a Bundle install, it say I must install missing gem ***"mysql -v '0.3.16'***";

I am able to install mysql -v ***'0.3.20'***, I have also tried to change the gem file in the app to mysql -v ***'0.3.20'***. rails installing mysql2 -v ***'0.3.20'*** instead of mysql -v ***'0.3.16'***

Comment: your question is not complete, you have not asked a question yet.

Comment: In your gemfile, did you add: `gem "mysql", "0.3.16"` ?? And lock it at that version? Then run `bundler update` ?

Comment: Hi Zhang, I  am new to rails and yes, the gem "mysql2, "0.3.16" is in the gem file and gemfile.lock. When I try to install the gem, mysql2 "0.3.20" is added but the application is asking for mysql2 "0.3.16"

Comment: i am getting a new error message when I run rake db:migrate on the app. It says Rake aborted,

Comment: i am getting a new error message when I run rake db:migrate on the app. It says Rake aborted, ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable. Could not find a javaScript runtime.c:/ blog/config/application.rb:7:in '(top (required))', .c:/ blog/rakefile.rb:4:in '(top (required))'